# String passed to store action (via mapActions) arrives as [object, Object]

Tags: vue.js, vuex, store

I am emitting an event from a child component, and then dispatching a store action (using mapActions) in a parent component. When that action is dispatched, the parent component passes a string to the action.

However, if I log that string that get passed to the store's action, I get `[object Object]`, and not the string, even though I've check the string before it gets passed to the action, and it looks good. What am I doing wrong???

In my parent component, I have

```
<ListItem v-for="item in listItems" :key="item.id" 
                 :item="item"
                 @remove="deleteListItem(`${item.id}`)"
      />
```

(ListItem is my child component).

In methods, I have

```
methods: {
...mapActions('listItems', ['deleteItem',],),
deleteListItem (id) {
  this.deleteItem(id);
},
```

},

In my listItems store, I have:

```
 deleteItem (id) {
    api.del(`${deleteURL}/${id}`);
  },
```

By the time id arrives at deleteItem, it is no longer the string I need.

Could anyone please provide some insight?

Comment: Try to test like this @remove="deleteListItem(item.id)" and then deleteListItem (id) { console.log(id)

Comment: yep, the id is all fine there...it's when i console.log it once it arrives in the store that it is not the string I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, in the child component pass the id as follows:

```
this.$emit('remove', this.item.id);
```

Then, the parent renders the child as follows:

```
<ListItem v-for="item in listItems" :key="item.id" 
          :item="item"
          @remove="deleteListItem"
/>
```

```
methods: {
...mapActions('listItems', ['deleteItem',],),
deleteListItem (id) {
     this.deleteItem(id);
},
```

Comment: When I do that, and console log 'id' as it arrives in the store, it is the instance of the store itself (getters: {…}, state: {…}, rootGetters: {…}, dispatch: ƒ, commit: ƒ, …})

Comment: Try this: deleteItem({commit}, id) if you want to commit and change the state in the store

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to wrap the argument in an object when I pass it to the store. Doing `this.deleteItem({id});` seemed to fix the issue...

Answer (score 0):

the first argument in vuex actions is the context object. If you don't want to use it and just use the payload you could use it like this:

```
deleteItem (_, id) {
  api.del(`${deleteURL}/${id}`);
},
```

[more info about context object](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions)